# Pass className,props,attributes from parent component to ALL child components without code duplication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component, react-functional-component

------------------------ React Parent Functional Component ------------------------

```
              <div style={{ width: "100%", overflow: "scroll", border: "1px solid #ecf0f1", margin: "10px 0px 0px 10px" }}>
                <svg id='wall' ref={wall} width="5000px" height="500px">
                  <PanelSvgs initColor={classes.greywall} selectPanel={selectPanel} />
                </svg>
              </div>
```

------------------------ React Child Functional Component ------------------------

```
function PanelSvgs(props) {
        return (
                <Fragment>
                        <polygon className={props.initColor} onClick={e => props.selectPanel(e)} bool="false" id="_x34_88_x2F_9" points="35.14,70.14 34.94,148.88 113.68,148.88 113.68,73.38"></polygon>
                        <polygon className={props.initColor} onClick={e => props.selectPanel(e)} bool="false" id="_x34_88_x2F_9" points="35.14,70.14 34.94,148.88 113.68,148.88 113.68,73.38"></polygon>
                        <rect className={props.initColor} onClick={e => props.selectPanel(e)} bool="false" id="_x36_01_x2F_12" x="34.94" y="148.88" width="78.74" height="78.74" ></rect>
                </Fragment>
}
export default PanelSvgs;
```

Hello everyone. As seen from the code snippets above. I have two react functional components, the parent and child.

I would like to pass down the className, onClick function and an attribute to all the "polygon and rect" objects. As I have approximately 2000 objects, is there a way to pass these attributes down in a simplified way instead of duplicating them across all 2000 objects.?

In Jquery and Javascript, it was relatively easy.

```
            const panels = document.getElementById('wall').children;

            // ADD onclick listener to children objects
            for (let p in panels) {
                let panel = panels[p];

                panel.onclick = () => {
                    selectPanel(panel);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it 2000 child components, all either `polygon` or `rect`, in a `Fragment`, that you simply want to always pass the same props to? Are they in some structure like an array that can be mapped? How are put in code?

Comment: @DrewReese Yeah. I get what you mean, that can be done easily.

` {childrenData.map(child => (
       <Child
         key={child.childNumber}
         text={child.childText} 
         onClick={e => {}    />  ))}`


But the backend people are lazy to turn the `polygon` or `rect` into an array/object. They are intending to keep these files in blob storage and send them to the front-end directly upon the API call

Comment: What is `childrenData`? can you post that? There are ways of working with react components that are in different structures: creating new, cloning, etc.. but without the details of the structure of the data you're working with it's not easy to answer. Hence why I asked how it is getting to your UI code.

Comment: There's no childrenData for now. I have to deal with the RAW svg below.

 `<svg id='wall' ref={wall} width="5000px" height="500px">
    <polygon className={props.initColor} onClick={e => props.selectPanel(e)} bool="false"></polygon>
                        <rect className={props.initColor} onClick={e => props.selectPanel(e)} bool="false" ></rect>
       .............
</svg> `

Currently, I used a useRef on the <svg> and get the wall.current.children components. But i have to manually key and assign the props to all the child components. which is a hassle. I want to do this dynamically.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks from the prompt reply btw! It's kind of irritating using React. The old ways of Jquery is so much more convenient.

Comment: Eh, I'd strongly disagree... I do everything in my power to remove jquery dependencies in anything I work with react-wise (they are kind of orthogonal to one another in their approach to UI). *But* they each solve their perspective use-cases (well ?) :)

Answer (score 1):

Would `cloneElement` work for you?

> Clone and return a new React element using `element` as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element’s props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace
>   existing children. `key` and `ref` from the original element will be
>   preserved.
>
> `React.cloneElement()` is almost equivalent to:
>
> `<element.type {...element.props} {...props}>{children}</element.type>`

Something like:

```
import React, { cloneElement} from 'react';

...

const elementProps = {
  className: props.initColor,
  onClick: props.selectPanel,
  bool: "false"
  id: "_x34_88_x2F_9"
  points: "35.14,70.14 34.94,148.88 113.68,148.88 113.68,73.38"
};

wall.current.children.map(element => cloneElement(element, elementProps));
```

This OFC, assumes you can get your data elements into an array form in order to iterate over them.